# Is there an R package for simulating a multivariate GARCH process with jump diffusion?

Tags: r

I'm looking for an R package and coding to simulate a multivariate Garch process with jump diffusion. Is there a package or R code I can replicate and modify?

Comment: Have you done any research of your own for such a package? I was able to find a few from a simple Google search.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search I found this paper: *High-dimensional GARCH process segmentation
with an application to Value-at-Risk* by Haeran Cho and Karolos K. Korkas. Link to their paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.01155.pdf).

In their abstract they reference their package, `segMGarch`, which is available on CRAN (Documentation can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segMGarch/segMGarch.pdf)).

I found this with very little effort. Consider looking into CRAN packages, other questions on StackOverflow (I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969962/simulation-of-garch-in-r?rq=1) in the related posts), or simply Googling it.